# Como Ocultar un Modal de Bootstrap

Tags: javascript, html, bootstrap

mi siguiente problema es cuando  intento ocultar la etiqueta ID Evento efectivamente me lo oculta, pero el modal se oculta, pero me bloquea lo demás elemento en el html y no se puede hacer nada por que bloquea el clic, pero se puede visualizar el website en la página web, habrá alguna forma de evitar esto, ya que uso Bootstrap pero me gustaria hacerlo sin usar JQuery solo Javascript Puro con el fin de aprender mas sin depender Jquery.

Espero su pronta respuesta gracias

Anexo el codigo fuente

````
 
// banner 
  <div id="Evento">
    <a href="#" target="_blank">
      <img class="oferta-r-e" src="imagen1-d" />
      <img class="img-fluid oferta-r-m" src="imagen-m" />
    </a>
  </div>

//modal

  <div id="Evento">
    <div class="modal fade in popup_cavas" id="myModal" role="dialog" style="top: 0px; background-color: rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.5)">
      <div class="modal-dialog">
        <div class="modal-content " style="background-image: url(img/popup.jpg)">
          <img src="" alt="" srcset="" />
          <button onclick=" close_anuncio()" type="button" class="close" data-dismiss="modal"><span aria-hidden="true">&times;</span><span class="sr-only">Cerrar</span></button>
          <button onclick=" relocate_home()" type="button" class="si">Si Soy Cliente!</button>
          <button onclick="close_anuncio()" class="no">No Soy</button>
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>





//JS

(function () {
  const etiqueta = document.querySelectorAll("#Evento"); // etiqueta de eventos
  const modalopen = document.getElementsByClassName("modal-open");

  let fecha = new Date();
  const fecha_actual = fecha;
  const diadelevento = new Date(2020, 10, 11);
  const findelevento = new Date(2020, 10, 16);
  //
  const fecha_inicio = diadelevento;
  const fecha_fin = findelevento;
  //
  if (fecha_actual >= fecha_inicio && fecha_actual <= fecha_fin) {
    for (var i = 0; i < etiqueta.length; i++) {
      etiqueta[i].style.display = "block";
      etiqueta[i].style.visibility = "visible";
    }
  } else {
    for (var i = 0; i < etiqueta.length; i++) {
      etiqueta[i].style.display = "none";
      etiqueta[i].style.visibility = "hidden";
    }

    // modal_evento.classList.remove("modal-open");
    // document.body.style.paddingRight = "0px";
    // modal_evento.style.overflow = "visible";
  }
  // console.log(modal_evento);
  // console.log(etiqueta);
  // console.log(etiqueta);
  // console.log(fecha_actual, "hoy");
  // console.log(fecha_inicio, "fecha_inicio");
  // console.log(fecha_fin, "fecha_fin");
})();


 <script type="text/javascript">
    $(function () {
      $("#myModal").modal();
    });

    function close_anuncio() {
      $("#myModal").modal("toggle");
    }

    function relocate_home() {
      location.href = "google.com";
    }
  </script> ```
````

Comment: Puedes hacerlo con JS, ya revisaste este enlace:? https://getbootstrap.com/docs/4.2/components/modal/#via-javascript

Comment: creo que es jquery, segun entiendo hasta la v5 de Bootstrap es donde quitan jquery.